# How to concatenate a variable with string in tikz for loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

Is it possible to concatenate a TikZ loop variable with a string? For example, consider the following tikzpicture

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name=AX]{A};
\node[name=BX, at={(1,0)}]{B};
\node[name=CX, at={(2,0)}]{C};
\foreach \i in {A,B,C} {
  \node[at=(\i{X})]{foo}; % FAIL HERE
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unsurprisingly, this code fails with the expected errors:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named `A{X}' is known. [}]
Package pgf Error: No shape named `B{X}' is known. [}]
Package pgf Error: No shape named `C{X}' is known. [}]
```

I am aware there are some workarounds, such as renaming `A-X` and then using `\i-X` in the loop, or looping over `AX, BX, CX` directly. But I am wondering if there is any way to directly concatenate `\i` with `X` to obtain `AX` etc. in the loop. For example, is there a command `\def{\ix}{\concatenate{\i}{X}}` or similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `{...}` and add a space between `\i` and `X`. This space will tell latex that the macro `\i` ended and that `X` is not part of the macro name, but it won't be included in the node name you are constructing:

(also using `#` for comments is wrong)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name=AX]{A};
\node[name=BX, at={(1,0)}]{B};
\node[name=CX, at={(2,0)}]{C};
\foreach \i in {A,B,C} {
  \node[at=(\i X)]{foo}; %# NO FAIL HERE
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```